# Setting c-basic-offset per directory in Emacs

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I have a C project that uses 2-space indents (in */projects/c*) and a C++ project with 4-space indents (in */projects/cpp*).  I can't figure out how to make Emacs automatically do the right spacing depending on where the file I open lives.

I can tell it to use `c++-mode` (4 spaces) for the .cpp files, but the .h files (in the cpp project) still default to `c-mode` (2 spaces).

Is there something I can put in my *.emacs* file to either indent .h files a different number of spaces or change the mode, depending on the directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directory Local Variables:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables

You can either use .dir-locals.el files, or alternatively you can configure it entirely in your .emacs file with the `dir-locals-set-class-variables` and `dir-locals-set-directory-class` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this in the first line of file for which the language is not deducible from the extension

```
// This may look like C code, but it really is -*- mode: c++ -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the `.h` files to `.hpp` do the trick?