# Emacs: how to toggle between two tab widths via hotkey

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm editing two different codebases in Emacs, one uses tabs set to two spaces and one uses tabs set to eight spaces (the Linux kernel).  Since the kernel uses tabs for alignment, I would like to adjust my tab size on the fly when I am working on kernel files.

I would like to be able to press M-2 to set the tab width to two, and M-8 to set the tab width to eight.  I would like these keys to work in all modes, whether I am working on C code, in a Makefile or even just a normal text file.  I want the rest of my active Emacs coding style to remain unchanged.

I'm a bit stuck because you use "setq" in the config files but this isn't a valid command with M-x, and trying to assign a function to the global key M-2 doesn't override the default function assigned to this key, and it seems I may have to use a hook or something for every type of file I want to edit, and this is very quickly getting way over my head!

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438275/setting-c-basic-offset-per-directory-in-emacs

Comment: @immerrr: Yes, the link at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables did provide a good (although different) solution.  But it would still be good to know how to achieve this as per my original question, just so that I better understand how Emacs works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of immerrr and camdez's answers to achieve what I was after:

```
(defun set-tab-width (len)
    (interactive "p")
    (setq tab-width len)
    (force-window-update)  ; Required or tabs are only updated line-by-line during editing
    (message "Tab width set to %d." len)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'set-tab-width)
```

This allows me to press `C-8 C-c t` to set a tab width of 8, or `C-2 C-c t` to set a tab width of two, or any other number to set different tab widths.

Answer (score 4):

To bind something to a key, it must be a *command*, which is Emacs name for function meant to be used interactively, so this is a function:

```
(defun set-c-basic-offset-2 ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 2))
```

and this is a command:

```
(defun set-c-basic-offset-2-command ()
  (interactive)
  (setq c-basic-offset 2))
```

Now you can do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-2") 'set-c-basic-offset-2-command)
```

Or, alternatively, you could do

```
(defun set-c-basic-offset-command (offset)
  (interactive "p")
  (setq c-basic-offset offset))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o") 'set-c-basic-offset-command)
```

And you could use <kbd>M-2 C-c o</kbd> and <kbd>M-8 C-c o</kbd> to set `c-basic-offset` to 2 or 8 respectively. Try reading docs for `interactive` function, it has a lot more to offer.

Comment: Be warned though, that binding to `M-2` directly will shadow its original binding which is `digit-argument`, so make sure you restore it before trying out the second example.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely do *not* want to clobber the default `M-2` and `M-8` bindings. *Much* better to use them to supply the numeric value, as immerrr has demonstrated. FYI, `C-c LETTER` (for any upper- or lower-case letter) and function keys `<f5>` to `<f9>` are reserved for end-users, and so completely safe to bind.

Comment: What's wrong with clobbering the default `M-2` and `M-8` bindings?  You can still access the same functionality with `C-2` and `C-8`, and `C-M-2` and `C-M-8` so it seems a little redundant to have three different keyboard shortcuts for the same action...

Comment: @immerrr: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Pressing the keyboard shortcuts has no effect in my init.el file, or a .c file.  Changing `c-basic-offset` to `tab-width` makes the keys change the tab width for a *single line* in my init.el but still has no effect in a .c file.

Comment: Malvineous: That redundancy is convenient, because it very frequently enables you to keep one single modifier held down while typing both the numeric argument and the command binding. e.g. `C-5 C-f` vs `M-5 M-f` -- in each case you just type `5 f` while holding the modifier. Clobber one of them and you lose that efficiency for a whole range of commands.

Comment: @Malvineous, by 'no effect' you mean that `c-basic-offset` remains the same or that indentation does not what is expected from it?

Comment: @immerrr: By 'no effect' I mean the tab width doesn't change, like I hadn't pressed the key at all.  Does it change for you e.g. in the `*scratch*` buffer?

Comment: @Malvineous, I see the same if after altering `c-basic-offset` I try to indent a single line surrounded by others which somehow override the setting. Indenting whole function works for sure for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't *precisely* what you asked for but this is something I actually use in my .emacs to accomplish the same task:

```
(defun camdez/toggle-tab-width ()
  "Toggles `tab-width' between 8 and 2."
  (interactive)
  (setq tab-width
        (if (= tab-width 2)
            8
          2))
  (message "Tab width set to %d." tab-width))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c TAB") 'camdez/toggle-tab-width)
```

It has a fairly logical mnemonic and doesn't clobber any other bindings.